# Android studio logcat not filtering by log level

Tags: android, android-studio

Android studio is not filtering anymore by level DEBUG and INFO, only ERROR and WARN works. It happens with any android studio version (from chipmunk to electriceel). So when i choose debug or info, it filters like with VERBOSE. Anyone have the same problem?

ADB version:

Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 33.0.3-8952118
Installed as /usr/local/bin/adb

Answer (score 0):

Try `Invalidating caches & Restart` by selecting all options.

[image]

Comment: i tried.. is not working. thx

Answer (score 0):

You can try restarting the logcat by pressing `Alt + 6` twice if invalidating caches and restarting doesn't help your problem.

Comment: on mac keyboard?

Comment: Nope, on Windows. perhaps [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-fix-android-studio-logcat-nothing-to-show-in-android-studio/) might help you.

Comment: nope.. i'm seriously thinking to format my mac

Comment: its command + 6 on mac.